# why the set of all functions in $L_{2}([a,b])$ which are positive almost everywhere on $[a.b]$ is convex (an example in Israel Gohberg)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

Why the set of all functions in $L_{2}([a,b])$ which are positive almost everywhere on $[a.b]$ is convex ? could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: Hint: What is a convex set ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because $tf(x)+(1-t)g(x)>t\cdot 0+(1-t)\cdot 0=0$ for a.e. $x$.

Comment: I think you mean $>$ (unless you consider $0$ to be positive).

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be convex and let $L_C = \{ f \in L_2[a,b] | f(t) \in C \text{ ae.} \}$,
then it is straightforward to see that $L_C$ is convex from the definition.

The set $C=[0,\infty)$ is convex.